# How to turn off a bluetooth speaker on windows shutdown?

Tags: windows-8.1, audio, bluetooth, shutdown, speakers

I bought these bluetooth speakers and have been listening to music via these from my Windows 8.1 Dell Laptop on Winamp. I presently turn on the speaker and it connects to my laptop and streams music over Bluetooth. That's fine for me until I shut down my pc.

Normally I shutdown my laptop at night and forget to turn off the bluetooth speaker. So once my machine is completely shut down and I'm half asleep, these speakers after being disconnected from the machine, alert with the sound "Bluetooth Speakers are ready to be connected".. cause they remain turned on, and are looking for devices to stream from. This is the main problem, and to resolve this I tried googling for "turn off bluetooth speakers on windows shutdown", but only found solutions for how to turn off windows bluetooth.

Please could someone help?
Thanks!

Comment: Do the speakers even support being turned off with a command sent via Bluetooth? Unless you know this is the case there's no point searching for a solution.

Comment: Nope... There's a button only. I thought some bluetooth app on windows could just turn it off... In terms of hardware, it's a soft button to turn it off, not a push toggle.

Comment: Obviously no app can do something the hardware itself doesn't support, so you'll need to confirm that somehow.

Comment: ok. Thanks! I'll check for manual online if any info is provided there... Thanks again!